# Magento Configurable Speed

Tags: magento

I've been doing some research on getting the configurable product speed in Magento to load faster. With especially 1600 simple products under that configurable product, the speed takes 12-18 seconds to load which is a killer.

So far i've tried to edit the core at my last try under:

app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Product/Collection.php

and edited the core with

an optimized version http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-performance-optimization-configurable-products-2

But even still it loads very slow, does anyone have an idea of how to speed under the configurable products?

Another route is changing under the Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable::getUsedProducts but even then I dont know where that's located at.

Please help. thanks

Comment: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable` = `Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php`

Comment: @benmarks thanks i should be able to go somewhere from there.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://github.com/magento/bugathon_march_2013/issues/148

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt I looked into it, however i dont think its for 1.7.0.2, some things break :( thanks though!

Comment: @benmarks would the magento compiler probably help with the speed?

Comment: Compiler would likely not be of much difference, and its use is no longer recommended. You should try though, no harm in it. Collection caching can also help.